# Framework/visual studio project type to use for unit testing .net standard libray?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, .net-standard

Given that the implementation of the `.net standard library` is provided by the underlined implementation (`.Net framework`, `.Net Core` (windows/Linux etc) ). And it is possible that the APIs have little different behaviour. `TimeZoneInfo.Id` provides different results based on the OS (last time I checked).

So, how to unit test? In visual studio we can either create a `.Net Core` `xUnit` project or `.Net Framework` `xUnit` project. How to run the same `xUnit` tests in two different environment?

Comment: _"TimeZoneInfo.Id provides different results based on the OS (last time I checked)...."_ - well were both OSs setup to be the same time zone; language; culture etc?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.standardname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ideally you need multiple unit test projects targeting different platforms you want to support, and they all link to your .NET Standard library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to multi-target the test project. That is, create a .NET Core xUnit project from the template and change

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

Note the change to plural / additional `s` here. The plural form allows you to specify multiple target frameworks to test on, so you could easily add multiple versions of .NET Core and .NET Standard.

While the VS-integrated test runner will only run the first framework at the moment (see [this tracking issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/298)), `dotnet test` on the console will run your tests on all specified configurations.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of targeting multiple runtimes, you could just as well use a test platform that is capable of running net standard tests by default. [Nuclear.Test](https://mikelimasierra.net/index.php/software-projects/nuclear-test-platform/) can help you with a more complete feature test of your implementation on multiple platforms.